# Ubuntu downloads everytime I boot up my computer

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, windows-7, downloads

I have downloaded Ubuntu with a usb on my computer which already has Windows 7. After I restart my computer, it needs the usb to finish the installation. If I take out the usb, the download fails. I checked the BIOS and the hard drive is Number 1. How do I fix this? I am a newbie with computers so please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your issue correctly,

1. Ensure you have made a bootable usb stick for ubuntu from windows. If not, please do this as suggested [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) .
2. If you have already done that, you need to go to bios and [change the boot order](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Your-Computer-to-Boot-from-USB-Flash-Drive).